# Doctrine Symfony DQL Join Complex SQL Many to Many

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am having an issue with Many to Many related table and Query Builder producing the correct sql.

location_googles is a table which is joined by another table holding the id's location_to_googles.

```
$queryBuilder = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->addSelect('vi.filename AS image')
    ->addSelect('vc.long_name as countryName, vcs.long_name as stateName, vcsc.long_name as cityName')
    ->leftJoin('v.location_googles', 'vc', 'WITH', "vc.type0 = :countrytypeid")
    ->setParameter('countrytypeid', 8)        
    ->leftJoin('v.location_googles', 'vcs', 'WITH', "vcs.type0 = :statetypeid")
    ->setParameter('statetypeid', 7)
    ->leftJoin('v.location_googles', 'vcsc', 'WITH', "vcsc.type0 = :citytypeid")
    ->setParameter('citytypeid', 5)
    ->leftJoin($imageEntityName, 'vi', 'WITH', "vi.parent = v.id")
    ->andWhere('v.status=:status')
    ->setParameter('status', 1)
    ->groupBy('v.id')
    ->orderBy($orderField, $orderDir);
```

The query builder ends up showing blank entries sometimes for countryName, stateName and cityName.

If I take the exported sql and change the entry from a left join to a regular join the data is populated, or a right join. But I cannot figure out how to get query builder to produce that.

Comment: Are you sure that every v record has a country?  Seems like you have some null relation values.  By the way, there is seldom a need to use the WITH clause for DQL.  DQL is smart enough to join based on your mapping data.

Comment: Not every v record has a country no. Would that stop records that do have a country from being populated? There are records that should be displaying a value and don't. Also how would I remove the WITH if I need the typeid to identify the country record, this table is filled with a mixture of countries, states, cities, etc...

Comment: So country, state and city are all in the same table?  I guess you do have a join issue of some kind but I would not care to guess the details.  Good luck.

Comment: indeed,   then doctrine would also not need the WITH,   and you wouldnt need to be using actual table names i guess ... , but no longer care to guess the details either, this one took enough of my rep already :)

Comment: What details would help you understand? DB Structure Map? Entity Code for the 2 entities?